# An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' - with structure

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, runtime-error, structure

I have a simple problem, but I can't solve it even with the Internet... I don't know what is wrong.

I defined a variable:

```
Dim paczka(1) As SenditAPI.singleSizesData
```

**singleSizesData** is a structure and I need an array of this structure

And then I try:

```
paczka(0).width = 10
paczka(0).height = 10
paczka(0).depth = 10
paczka(0).weight = 4
paczka(0).COD = 0
paczka(0).INS = 5
paczka(0).content = "Test"
```

I get the "**An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'**" error. I really don't know why.

Comment: On which line do you get that error? I tried a quick example and your code and it works perfectly ok.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth No I haven't initialised but I tried and I got the same error in the same place. In documentation is written that `singleSizesData` is an array structure.

@PradeepKumar I get that error in this line - `paczka(0).width = 10`

Comment: If you are getting error on that line, then surely your `singleSizesData` is not a structure but a class. This is because strucures don't need to be initialized, while classes do need initialization (using the new keyword). You can verify this by initializing it like `paczka(0) = New SenditAPI.singleSizesData` before that line. If it works, then surely it is a Class, and not a Structure. Please verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that `SenditAPI.singleSizesData` is a structure but in order to get the error you experience it must be a class because clearly `paczka(0)` is null and structures cannot be null. So the problem is that you create an array with null references that you then try to dereference resulting in the exception.

You will have to create a new `SenditAPI.singleSizesData` instance before assigning its members:

```
paczka(0) = new SenditAPI.singleSizesData
paczka(0).width = 10
paczka(0).height = 10
paczka(0).depth = 10
paczka(0).weight = 4
paczka(0).COD = 0
paczka(0).INS = 5
paczka(0).content = "Test"
```